# How to reuse a Django template?

Tags: django, html, python-3.x, templates

Currently, I have almost two exact same templates and they use the same Django form, but there is only 1 parameter that changes in these two forms which is the action method, that is,

**Django form**

```
class DropDownMenu(forms.Form):
    week = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x,x) for x in range(1,53)]
    year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x,x) for x in range(2015,2030)]
```

**template 1**

```
<form id="search_dates" method="POST" action="/tickets_per_day/">
    <div class="row">
       <div style="display:inline-block">
            <h6>Select year</h6>
              <select name="select_year">
                <option value={{form.year}}></option>
              </select>
       </div>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**template 2**

```
<form id="search_dates" method="POST" action="/quantitative_analysis/">
    <div class="row">
       <div style="display:inline-block">
            <h6>Select year</h6>
              <select name="select_year">
                <option value={{form.year}}></option>
              </select>
       </div>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The only thing that varies is the action method, so I would like to know if it is possible to re-use one template that varies only in the action method. If it is possible, can you help me with the code?

I checked this question [django - how to reuse a template for nearly identical models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906296/django-how-to-reuse-a-template-for-nearly-identical-models) but I am not using any model here with my templates.

Comment: can you send the action attribute from view set itself,then you can reuse template

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course there is a way. [`{% include %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#include) to the rescue!

Create a base template for your form, like this:

```
<!-- form_template.html -->

<form id="search_dates" method="POST" action="{{ action }}">
    <div class="row">
       <div style="display:inline-block">
            <h6>Select year</h6>
              <select name="select_year">
                <option value={{form.year}}></option>
              </select>
       </div>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Notice the placeholder `action`. We'll need it in the next step.

Now, you can reuse this template, by simply writing:

```
<!-- a_template.html -->

{% include 'form_template.html' with action='/tickets_per_day/' %}


<!-- b_template.html -->

{% include 'form_template.html' with action='/quantitative_analysis/' %}
```

Comment: Just for the record: use `with action=/tickets_per_day/` where `action=...` does not contain any spaces, otherwise you will encounter the error `Django with tag not recognizing keyword argument`

Answer (score 1):

Well from your views you can pass `action` in the context and use that in template in this way you don't have to create two separate templates. Lets say the template name is `abc.html` used by two views:

```
def my_view_a(request):
    ctx = {'action': '/tickets_per_day/'}
    return render(request, 'abc.html', ctx)

def my_view_b(request):
    ctx = {'action': '/quantitative_analysis/'}
    return render(request, 'abc.html', ctx)
```

Then in template you would simply do:

```
<form id="search_dates" method="POST" action="{{ action }}">
```

In the above code the action is hardcoded better to use [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) to resolve url path by name:

```
ctx = {'action': reverse('namespace:url_name')}  # replace namespace and url_name with actual values
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in `template2`:

```
{% include "template1.html" with form=form %}
```

It will work.